# How can I copy the text from remote emacs to the local without hightlighting it?

Tags: emacs, putty, yank

Local: windows 7; Remote: Linux

In putty, I use emacs -nw to write some code. When I want to copy into my local windows, I highlight it. But it shows with line number

```
15-|aaa
16-|BBB
17-|cccc
```

So highlighting it doesn't work. Then I think using mark set and yank them. But it can only copy the text between the remote program. How can I deal with that problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can infer from your "putty" tag that you're using Windows locally, but it would help your question if you were explicit in the text about what "local" and "remote" mean.

Comment: I've removed your irrelevant "localization" tag. I simply can't tell whether or not the "remoting" tag is another mistake, but in general please read the descriptions of the tags before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to turn off line numbers: `(global-linum-mode 0)`.

It's possible to get what you want, but it probably isn't worth the effort. You'll have to set up X forwarding, which is a system that lets you send a whole window over the network. Usually this is unacceptably slow for something like text editing. But if you really did do that, you can add `(setq interprogram-pate-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)` to you `.emacs` and it should "just work".